# spring-mvc when to use @CookieValue

Tags: java, spring-mvc, cookies

In a controller when should you use @CookieValue ? 
Only when you know that you are sure that the cookie will be present ?

I have this controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("my")
public class MyController {


    @RequestMapping("")
    public ModelAndView index(@CookieValue("myCookie") String cookie,
                        Map<String, Object> model){

     log.info("My cookie {}", cookie);

     (...)
}
```

When the cookie is set, no problem the method is called, but when the cookie is not set the method is not called and I think I can not have another method in my controller mapped to the same path.

(my version of Spring: 3.2.3)

Comment: Have you tried making the CookieValue optional ? `@CookieValue(value="myCookie", required=false)`

Comment: @Kal, gee thanks I feel so ashamed !

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Answered by Kal in the comment,I put the answer to mark the question as answered/closed.

`@CookieValue` has a required parameter which is set on true by default.

So,

```
@CookieValue(value="myCookie", required=false)
```

solved my problem.

Comment: In that case you should mark this as the accepted answer, because at the moment the question is still unanswered.

Comment: And you must give reps to Kal ;)

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you also can use attribute "defaultValue".
It's look like:

```
@CookieValue(value="name", defaultValue="someValue")
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion:

cookie `default` -- the logical hide the following statements from exam whether it has cookie or not because it always has one(default or not)

cookie `required` -- the logical need to exam whether it has cookie and doing the corresponed action.